# I messed up my zshrc on a remote server and now I can't run any commands!

Tags: ssh, zsh

On a remote machine I changed my `zsh` settings and it is now broken,
for every keypress it says: "url-quote-magic:1: url-quote-magic: function definition file not found "

I don't have another account on that machine, What can I do to disable the faulty `.zshrc` so that I can use my shell again and fix it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can run a command on the remote server without logging in like this:

```
ssh -lUSERNAME SERVER COMMAND
```

e.g.

```
ssh -lsomeuser someserver 'mv .zshrc .zshrc.bak'
```

The command given as last argument to `ssh` will be executed by a non-interactive shell and commands from `.zshrc` are only executed by interactive shells (see [`zsh` manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/1/zsh), section on startup and shutdown files).

Comment: Yes that works fine! Thanks. Although I use a "key" to login and for me it looks like: `ssh servername 'mv .zshrc .zshrc.broken'`

Answer (score 4):

I could also sftp to the server and overwrite the `.zshrc` with an empty file or with one that works!

Answer (score 3):

Here, it's easy because the file you've messed up is only used by interactive logins. If you'd messed up `~/.zshenv`, or if your login shell was bash and you'd messed up `~/.bashrc` (weirdly, bash reads `~/.bashrc` if it's a non-interactive login shell and its parent is `rshd` or `sshd`), none of the methods that rely on executing a command non-interactively would work.

SSH insists on running a shell. If you have no other way to log in (via another account or via a method other than ssh), then your only recourse is to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> really fast after you're authenticated and before the shell reaches the problematic line. In practice, this can often be done manually; it may help to arrange for the machine to be heavily loaded (CPU or disk). If you have trouble pressing the keys at the right time, try using `expect`.

Answer (score 1):

I could have changed my shell to `bash` using:

```
ssh -luser server 'chsh -s /bin/bash'
```

assuming bash is available on the server and it works for me.

Answer (score 1):

This issue just happened to me (d'oh!), and I fired up my gui text editor, [TextWrangler, to connect to my remote server](https://www.cnet.com/how-to/how-to-use-textwrangler-as-a-remote-file-editor/), then via TextWrangler > Open from FTP/SFTP server, went to .zshrc on my remote server, fixed the file (edited a bad PATH line), saved the fixed file, restarted my terminal, and the problem was resolved. Hello again, Zsh!

[BBEdit](https://www.barebones.com/products/bbedit/benefitscommand.html) is another free editor (same company, Bare Bones Software, Inc.) that allows access to files on remote servers (TextWrangler is still available, but has been sunsetted).

Answer (score 0):

I tried to do a remote edit with vim:

```
vim sftp://user@server/.zshrc
```

which didn't work. Although `:Nread sftp://server/.zshrc` could load the broken `.zshrc` file and `:Nwrite` could write it back (I have my public key on the server and ssh without a password).

Still more solutions are very welcome.